# Как правильно переименовать проект?

Tags: java, android, gradle

Есть проект **A**. Его нужно переименовать в проект **B**.

Как правильно нужно переименовать проект и что в нем нужно изменить, чтобы при установке двух apk **A** и **B** приложения не затирали друг друга, а были двумя разными приложениями на телефоне?

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+vitaxafication/posts/ebAb4oF4nWF, http://awesomedevelop.blogspot.ru/2015/01/how-to-change-packagename.html

Comment: @iFr0z Спасибо!

Comment: Рад был помочь! :)

Comment: @iFr0z, вы б в ответ бы написали б)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб исправился:)

Comment: Удивлён что в андроид студии до сих пор нет кнопки на подобии "изменить имя пакета", и даже в популярном инструменте для работы с APK – _APK Easy Tool_ нет такой функции. Очень странно, ведь проблема вроде как актуальная.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Необходимо открепить объединение средних имен в пакете, для этого нужно выбрать параметры отображения структуры проекта, которая находится над самой текстурой и убрать галочку **"Compact Empty Middle Packages"**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда имена будут откреплены, каждое из имён можно изменить отдельно. Меняем необходимые имена выбрав из контекстного меню `Refactor` – > `Rename` или **Shift+F6**. При появлении предупреждения нажимаем `Rename Package`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При изменении первого имени пакета – com/ru/ua необходимо нажать “*Rename all*”, т.к. внутри этой папки расположены паки библиотек, в которых так же необходимо заменить имена.

Теперь имя пакета изменено, связи в классах переписаны, но настройки проекта еще не знают, что мы что-то сделали. Для оповещения открываем `build.gradle (Module:app)`, находим в нём следующий участок кода:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.name.test" // изменить на новое нужное
    minSdkVersion ...
    targetSdkVersion ...
    versionCode ...
    versionName "..."
}
```

и изменяем имя пакета на новое. В большинстве случаев `Gradle` сам определит, что были внесены изменения и предложит синхронизироваться с проектом, показав соответствующее уведомление в правом верхнем углу. Но если этого не произошло, то необходимо выполнить синхронизацию вручную. Для этого отправляемся в меню `Tools –> Android –> Sync Project With Gradle Files`.

Последнее что осталось сделать, так это изменить имя пакета в манифесте, хотя для активностей имена уже будут изменены. Открываем файл манифеста `AndroidManifest.xml` и в самом верху изменяем имя:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.name.test"> // изменить на новое нужное
```

Если после выполнения всех шагов `Android Studio` не сможет инициализировать `R.java`, и будут выводиться уведомления `Cannot resolve symbol R`, то необходимо очистить проект, перейдя в соответствующее меню `Build -> Clean Project`.

[Источник](http://awesomedevelop.blogspot.ru/2015/01/how-to-change-packagename.html)

---

Если скучно читать, то посмотрите [видео](https://plus.google.com/+vitaxafication/posts/ebAb4oF4nWF)

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю вашему вниманию простой консольный инструмент на Python3 который решает любую задачу по смене пакета, разработчиком которого я и являюсь:
https://github.com/PrincessYork/AndroidProjectRenamer

Меняет имя пакетов во всех файлах проекта, создаёт новое дерево папок и перемещает туда файлы. Так что больше не надо пыхтеть с рефакторингом пакетов.

Comment: Princess_York, на этом сайте нужно указывать прямо в ответе, что Вы (судя по имени автора репозитория GitHub) являетесь разработчиком AndroidProjectRenamer. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Спасибо за комментарий, исправил.