# Как изменить имя пакета в проекте AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, package

При создании проекта AndroidStudio спрашивает каким будет пакет. Как этот пакет изменить без геморроя? Неужели нет инструмента?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551017/205563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственное что нашлось на просторах, это советы делать рефакторинг имён папок внутри студии, создавать новые папки, удалять старые, делать реплейс старого пакета на новый. Это ужасно. Ужасно что не было до сих пор ни одного инструмента который бы помог разработчику просто взять и ввести в текстовое поле нужное ему имя пакета, и моментально поменять его.
Но теперь такой инструмент есть, потому что мне надоело всё время делать рефакторинг и самому создавать директории, и я решил сам сделать такой инструмент:
https://github.com/PrincessYork/AndroidProjectRenamer