# Не удается загрузить приложение в google play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Я не знаю как переименовать название проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Публиковать проекты со стандартным именем пакета "com.example" запрещено. Вы можете изменить название пакета на любое удобное вам, и загрузить новый апк в маркет.

1) Сначала измените названия пакетов.

2) Откройте build.gradle (Module:app) и измените имя пакета на новое.

3) Откройте файл манифеста AndroidManifest.xml и в самом верху измените имя.

Подробное описание всех действий в [этом ответе на русском Stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551017/195759).